# end date validation

Tags: php

I would like validate the current date with question posted date if date difference is greater then 1 day then it needs to show in over due question also this will not consider the array of dates which are already i having in my array.

Like if a question posted on 20-July-11.

exemption date array {'21-July-11', ... etc} 
current date is 22-July-11

then the output needs to be shown like question is waiting for 1 day instead of 2 days.

can any one help on it.

Comment: can you post more detailed info? Like: where do you store your dates? If you store questions in database, mybe it would be easier to compare dates at sql level when you pull data out from DB?

Comment: am stored the question details into my db. with date added as in datetime format. also am maintaining an array of exemption date in a table. both are in datetime format.

Comment: in that case it would be much easier to create a SQL query which would pull only the records you are intrested in and then add all results to the array in php...

Comment: I need the to show the list of all questions asked and one more columns that shows how long old this question was asked.

Comment: Provided you can use sql to do that, see my example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is some example code I have created for you to calculate the due date. When you submit a question, calculate the due date that way and store it in the database with entry for that question...

```
<?php

$daysDue = 2;
$exDatesArray = array("2011-07-21", "2011-07-23"); //array with all your holiday dates.
$question_1_Date = "2011-07-21";
$question_2_Date = "2011-07-18";
$question_3_Date = "2011-07-20";

echo "Holidays on: ";
foreach( $exDatesArray AS $exdate )
{
    echo $exdate . ", ";
}
echo "<br/><br/>";
echo "submit date -> due date<br/>";
echo $question_1_Date . " -> " . calculateDueDate( $question_1_Date, $exDatesArray, $daysDue ) . "<br/>";
echo $question_2_Date . " -> " . calculateDueDate( $question_2_Date, $exDatesArray, $daysDue ) . "<br/>";
echo $question_3_Date . " -> " . calculateDueDate( $question_3_Date, $exDatesArray, $daysDue );

function calculateDueDate( $date, $exDates, $daysDue )
{
    //start with day 1
    $count = 1;

    //now we loop from day one to due days
    while( $count <= $daysDue )
    {
        //add one day to start date
        $date = add_date( $date, 1 );
        //check if that new date is a holiday
        if( !in_array($date , $exDates) )
        {
            //only if it is not a holiday we increase counter, otherwise we dont count that day towards due period
            $count++;
        }
    }

    //return calculated due date
    return $date;
}

function add_date($date,$days)
{ 
    $cd = strtotime($date); 
    return date('Y-m-d', mktime(0,0,0,date('m',$cd),date('d',$cd) + $days, date('Y',$cd))); 
}
?>
```

Output:

```
Holidays on: 2011-07-21, 2011-07-23, 

submit date -> due date
2011-07-21 -> 2011-07-24
2011-07-18 -> 2011-07-20
2011-07-20 -> 2011-07-24
```

Comment: Consider my scenario, admin needs to reply a all the questions posted by customer. If admin not answered the question with in 2 days then it needs to be show as over due question. consider if a customer posted a question on 20-july-11. admin needs to respond with in 22-july-11, suppose 21st is an holiday. i have stored this date in exemption_dates table itself. so this kind of situation it needs to show this question as overdue on 23 -July- 11 instead of showing overdue in 22-July-11. What was the sql i needs to use here. could you please help me.

Comment: ah i see what you need now. next time try to explain the question better at the beginning. Give me few minutes I will try to figure out the best solution...

Comment: sure i'll clearly explain my upcoming days question. thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: If you want to calculate that stuff for every question AFTER the question have been inserted into the database, you might have a problem. That way would be inefficient and with large amount of questions (after some time) operation like that might take alot of time. IMO the best solution here would be to calculate something like dueDate at the time when the question is beeing posted, and store it in the table with questions... Then the query to select overdue questions would be quick and simple, saving your time and resources...

Comment: Yes daniel its worked fine for me. I have added one more column for due date and updated by the time of posting the question. and i have checked the due date with the current date in the listing page itself. once again thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
//convert date to unixtime (seconds)
$question_sec = strtotime($question);

//subtract
$diff = time() - $question_sec;
$days = $diff / 60*60*24;
echo "$days old";
```

Comment: not complete, you did not consider the array of dates to ignore

Comment: @rabudde That's because I could barely understand the question.